# "turning to fish as a cheap and healthy alternative"

Tags: meaning-in-context, ielts

Here's the IELTS recording:

> But eating patterns have changed in countries like the UK, where fish was once considered as food for the poor rather than the rich. People have been turning to fish as a cheap and healthy alternative to meat, driving up demand and depleting stocks. Food scares like BSE and foot-and-mouth disease have also driven people away from eating meat, which again is invariably replaced by fish.

*IELTS TEST BUILDER 1* - TEST 4 [Audio](https://youtu.be/PNUs1cpOnlM?t=24m51s)

The question is: "In the UK…

A - "fish used to be seen as a luxury"
B - "fish is not cheaper than meat"
C - "fish used to be seen as a cheap meal"
D - "food scares have driven people away from eating fish".

B (right answer) - "fish is not cheaper than meat"

I chose C "fish used to be seen as a cheap meal"

I don't understand why C is a wrong answer and B is right. "People have been turning to fish as a cheap ... alternative to meat" - to my mind as a cheap alternative it's (fish) cheaper than meat.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68244/discussion-on-question-by-kuku-turning-to-fish-as-a-cheap-and-healthy-alternati).

Comment: One comment (reposted from the comments moved to chat). The source of this question is not an official IELTS question booklet. It's published by MacMillan and not by Cambridge ESOL (who publish the official ones). It's possible that (C) is the correct answer, and the people who wrote the book just had the question to work with, and managed to make a mistake in the answer.

Comment: Do not use comments to answer (post an [answer](/help/how-to-answer) instead), praise or rebuke ([vote](/help/why-vote) instead), discuss ([chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) instead), suggest edits ([edit](/help/privileges/edit) instead), or comment on site design or policy (post at [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead). Use comments to [ask for clarification, suggest changes, or offer short-lived information](/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Because comments have been deleted, and especially the comment where I pointed out that [Macmillan](http://macmillan.com/) is a trusted, established, and highly-respected English publisher that has printed hundreds of books to help candidates, and students alike to learn English as a second language and pass English exams. They are, therefore, not hacks, they have a reputation to maintain. This is not to say that editors never make mistake, they do, but special care is taken over exam material.

Answer (score 13):

**I strongly believe you are correct**, and the IELTS have made an error (To err is human!). I think you should contact them and ask for an explanation of their answer. Examiners & organisations do make mistakes!
Here is my reasoning as to why B cannot be correct.

> B. Fish *is not* cheaper than meat

This statement is in the **present** tense.

Here is the original statement...

> People **have been turning** to fish *as a cheap* and healthy
>   alternative to meat

This uses the [present perfect progressive tense](https://leo.stcloudstate.edu/grammar/tenses.html), which indicates the condition is ongoing **into the present** (and possibly the future)! Here's a definition...

> Present perfect progressive tense describes an action that began in
>   the past, continues in the present, and may continue into the future.
>   This tense is formed by using has/have been and the present participle
>   of the verb (the verb form ending in -ing).

Thus, B cannot be correct, *fish MUST be cheaper than meat*, and your answer C is the only one left unfalsified.

> C. Fish used to be seen as a cheap meal.

Good luck challenging the IELTS! Right is on your side!

Comment: thank you so much both for your explanation and wishing me luck! Present continous (they teach us so) also gave me reason to chose C.

Comment: I'm really pleased you are challenging their answer Kuku! You won't be alone in choosing C and being puzzled by their response, because it's wrong!

Answer (score 4):

Let's eliminate as many options as possible

> …where fish was **once considered as food for the poor** rather than the rich.

This excerpt excludes **A**) *fish used to be seen as a luxury*

> Food scares like BSE and foot-and-mouth disease have also driven people away **from eating meat**

That clearly contradicts **D**) *food scares have driven people away from eating fish*

We have **B**) and **C**) left.

> People have been turning to fish as **a cheap and healthy alternative** to meat, **driving up demand** and depleting stocks.

That fish was seen to be less expensive was true in the *past* but today the cost of fish has risen due to its **high demand**. In the excerpt, "a healthy and cheap alternative to meat" does not imply fish is ***cheaper*** than meat. Thus, **B**) *fish is not cheaper than meat* is the correct answer.

EDIT

> **C)** fish **used to** be seen as a cheap meal

Answer C employs, what is called a [semi-auxiliary verb](https://www.thoughtco.com/habitual-past-grammar-1690829), **used**. It is used to describe **habits and habitual actions in the past.** The British Council's page: *[Past habit – used to/would/past simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/past-habit-used-towouldpast-simple)* explains its meaning and usage very clearly: “Remember that ‘used to’ is only for past states/actions that don’t happen now – we can’t use it for things that still happen now”. If anything, the statement is reflected in the sentence:

> …where fish was **once considered as food for the poor** rather than the rich.

Consequently, option C is not incorrect but **it is not the main message** of the speaker. By stating “In the UK fish used to be seen as a cheap meal” the candidate is ignoring the main point being discussed, that is, fish supplies are running low and their price is steadily increasing. I believe the examiners (or authors) were looking for a line that summarised that particular passage. If fish was cheaper in the past, it stands to reason that it is *no longer true in the present*.

Therefore, **B**) appears to be the better answer, but only *just*.

Comment: The price of fish may indeed have gone up due to a change in demand, but nowhere does it say that the price has risen to be higher than meat.  In fact the way I read the sentence “*People have been turning to fish as a cheap alternative...*” means that this is a recent phenomenon and that it is still occurring- which can’t be true if fish is now more expensive.

Comment: The quoted paragraph could easily be followed by: “If these trends continue, the price of fish could easily exceed that of meat  within the next 2 years.”

Comment: *Fish as a cheap... alternative to meat* may not explicitly state that fish is cheap*er*, but it doesn't rule out the possibility (even if fish has recently increased in price - in turn barely even implied, as this is a question about English not supply/demand economics). If we're into implications then it would be valid to read it as *fish is cheaper than meat*. But anyway the logic of B doesn't work. If we can't read the text as saying fish is cheaper, still less can we read it as saying fish is not cheaper. C is unambiguously correct. B requires logic chopping and economic assumptions.

Comment: @Jim yes, .....have been turning... not the most precise turn of phrase, but I believe the authors were looking for a line that summarised the final part of the talk. Sentence C) is clearly referring to the past though....`fish used to be seen as a cheap meal`

Comment: @kuku I am just glad that your question wasn't deleted, unlike the [first time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/414722/i-dont-understand-why-b-is-the-right-answer-in-an-audio-test), and it has attracted a sizeable number of views. Whether my answer is wrong or right is unimportant, the more upvotes an answer receives the more you should trust it. In this case, Harry Tuttle's.

Comment: @kuku please do not edit or attempt to undelete your previous question. It should stay deleted. This 2nd version is much clearer, has an audio link which supports your question, and it has three answers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, the my previous question was my first ever. I couldn't edit it (and I never did, neither tried to undelete) as I was waiting for messages in my email, stating I have comments). When I finally checked it (after being on a trip), it was too late. Thank you so much again for the comments and editing

Answer (score 3):

As I mention at the bottom of this answer, I think this is a poor question that is unnecessarily confusing, but the likely justification for designating the answer as **B** is easier to see when observing the passage in its entirety.

---

I think it's important to listen to the entire recording in this case, and not just the portion cited in the question.  Although the portion cited is the part that references "The UK" in particular, the message of the entire passage is more clearly focused on **the increased demand for** and **scarcity of** fish since the 1970's, so the **primary** message is, as [Mari-Lou A](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/417158/228732)'s answer details, the focus on *scarcity,* and hence that fish has become more expensive than it was before.

In this transcription of the complete passage, I highlighted in bold portions that I think are especially relevant.

> I would like to focus on the current problems in the fishing industry in Europe, and **in particular the present scarcity of marine fish**...
>
> A statistic to begin with: **Since the 1970's, stocks of the most heavily fished species have fallen on average by 90%.**  And why has this happened?  Well, there's a chain of events that begins with the demographic changes that have taken place in the world over the last century.  During this time, the world population has grown at a phenomenal rate, with efficient and heavy fishing which is technology driven meeting the **increasing demands for food.**  ... as a consequence, **many fishing stocks in European waters... are now on the verge of collapse.**  But the problem is not restricted to European waters.  It's a situation that's all too clear all around the world.  **Fish stocks in the Pacific Ocean, for instance, are now on the verge of collapse**, due to a combination of over-fishing and natural changes in Ocean ecology.  And there's another reason behind the increased demand for fish, and that is the changes in eating patterns of different countries.  Certain countries have a long tradition of fishing, for example, the Southern European countries.

And the portion already cited:

> But eating patterns have changed in countries like the UK, where fish was once considered as food for the poor rather than the rich. People have been turning to fish as a cheap and healthy alternative to meat, driving up demand and depleting stocks. Food scares like BSE and foot-and-mouth disease have also driven people away from eating meat, which again is invariably replaced by fish.

However, having made this point, I also believe that this is a poorly written and confusing question, specifically because of the prompt *"In the UK*".  This line draws attention to the final portion of the text, which does mention that one reason people have turned to fish is because it is a "*cheap* and healthy" alternative to meat.  There's no question that this makes the prompt confusing when it asks specifically about the status of fish *In the UK*.

So my conclusion is that it is a poor question, but the reason the answer is designated **B** is likely because of the overarching message of the passage is focused on scarcity of fishing stocks, increased demand for fish, and thus that fish is becoming more expensive.

Comment: As already observed in other comments, the argument for B relies on a chain of inferences based on certain assumptions of classical free-market economics along with a number of "all other things being equal" assumptions, _none_ of which is supported by the passage (even the more extended version of it). A rise in demand does not necessarily raise prices; it might just be putting out-of-work fishing boats and their crews back in business. Stocks "on the verge of collapse" may not _yet_ be much harder to catch. Meat may have risen in price due to increased regulation. And so forth.

Comment: @DavidK I agree with you, and I can't say I've read all the comments, especially those that were moved to chat, but I think this answers the question "why is it B" while acknowledging that I don't really believe the argument is reasonable, which is why I emphasized that I do think it's a flawed question.

Comment: It seems we agree about what chain of reasoning was probably in the test-writers' minds when they selected B as the answer (assuming someone did not just copy the wrong letter at some point in the process). And now we both have expressed skepticism about the correctness of that reasoning, so that clears up the only point where I formerly thought we might disagree.